# Select all records in GROUP even when there are no corresponding data at the moment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

Looking for a way to include in the result all "CASE WHEN" options. So even if there is no record falling into `Range` of 'Between 1 and 14 days' and `MyOrder` = 1, the final result shall contain such a record. `Suma` and `Docs` can be empty or equal to 0 for these rows.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(b.Range) Nazwa, SUM(b.Left) Suma, COUNT(*) Docs
FROM
    (SELECT
         CASE
             WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 
                 THEN 'Between 1 and 14 days'
             WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 
                 THEN 'Between 15 and 30 days'
             ELSE 'Over 30 days'
         END AS Range,
         CASE
             WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 1 AND 14 THEN 1
             WHEN a.DaysLate BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN 2
             ELSE 3
         END AS MyOrder,
         Amount, DaysLate
     FROM 
         (#subquery) a) b
GROUP BY 
    b.MyOrder
```

All solutions I have found so far relay on final `JOIN` with table containing all potential values of `CASE`. But this creates a kind of redundancy. Is there any easier way to implement this?

I am using Azure SQL with database compatibility level set to 150.

Comment: Seems like you want a use the `VALUES` operator to construct your boundaries, and then `LEFT JOIN` to your table. Difficult to give an answer without Sample Data and Expected Results.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "a kind of redundancy".

Comment: @GordonLinoff By "a kind of redundancy" I meant that you have to put in the code values like `Between 1 and 14 days` twice - once in `CASE`, and second time in another table which will be joined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use a generic tier table.  This way I can serve multiple masters and keep the logic out of the code.

The following is an over simplified demonstration

**Example**

```
Declare @Tier table (Tier_Name varchar(50),Tier_R1 int, Tier_R2 int,Tier_Desc varchar(100))
Insert Into @Tier values
 ('DAYSLATE', 1, 14    ,'Between 1 and 15 days')
,('DAYSLATE',15, 30    ,'Between 15 and 30 days')
,('DAYSLATE',31, 999999,'Over 30 days')

Declare @SampleData table (DaysLate int,Amount money)
Insert Into @SampleData values
 (8,25000)
,(10,1000)
,(22,50000)
,(90,60000)


Select Tier_Desc
      ,Amount = sum(Amount)
      ,Cnt    = sum(1)
 From  @Tier A
 Join  @SampleData B
   on  Tier_Name='DAYSLATE' and DaysLate between Tier_R1 and Tier_R2
 Group By Tier_R1,Tier_Desc
 Order By Tier_R1
```

**Returns**

```
Tier_Desc               Amount      Cnt
Between 1 and 15 days   26000.00    2
Between 15 and 30 days  50000.00    1
Over 30 days            60000.00    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived table *intelligently*:

```
SELECT v.range as Nazwa, SUM(a.Left) as Suma, COUNT(*) as Docs
FROM (VALUES ('Between 1 and 14 days', 1, 14, 1),
             ('Between 15 and 30 days', 15, 30, 2),
             ('Over 30 days', 31, null, 3)
     ) v(range, lo, hi, ord) left join
     (#subquery) a
     ON a.dayslate >= v.lo AND
        (a.dayslate <= v.hi or v.hi IS NULL)
GROUP BY v.range
ORDER BY ord;
```

Comment: Good solution and works nice, however I found John's solution more appealing to me as it solves my problem globally.

Comment: @Megrez7 . . . Thank you for the explanation.  John usually has well-thought out answers.